# Not able to use c8y.ui functionality on top of cumulocity's hello-core-api example application

Tags: angularjs, cumulocity

I'm trying to use functionality provided c8y.ui module (http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/core/c8y.ui) in an application I'm building on top of Cumulocity's hello-core-api application (https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-examples/src/0fbc406e849ecba3a01526ebef8d4d8bb1f7f374/hello-core-api).

However when I inject a dependancy from the c8y.ui module to my controller I get the following error message (when trying to inject c8yAlert as dependancy)

angular.js:9997 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: c8yAlertProvider <- c8yAlert

Any ideas on how I could get the c8y.ui module working too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `c8y.ui` is not included in [Smart apps toolkit](https://github.com/Cumulocity/cumulocity-clients-javascript). However you can use one of alert/notification javascript libraries out there ([see here](http://techslides.com/50-plugins-for-alerts-and-notifications)).

---

Edit: Nevermind, apparently it's included.

---

Basically, you are not supposed to use `c8yAlert` in Smart apps toolkit. Most of the stuff in `c8y.ui` rely on custom Cumulocity DOM, styles and combination of them in a particular way. If you need to display alerts/notifications, you should rely on 3rd party libraries.

`c8yAlert` is documented because you can use it in a Cumulocity plugin code.